# Managing Server Load - Flask SQLAlchemy Postgres on Heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I have a Flask application I've built that uses Twilio and the OpenAI API to help political campaigns send text messages.

The system worked fine in my earlier test with ~25 concurrent users. I tried a more significant test today with 200 users, and it started to fall apart. Most of the time, it works fine, but occasionally, incoming messages are dropped, or Twilio can't hit my callback url without an error.

Do you have any thoughts on how I can address or areas I should check? Happy to share more details.

I'm using a standard-0 database and 5 standard 2x dynos.

I tried adding a few more dynamos to see if that would help, but I'm still seeing drops. I have a hypothesis that it has something to do with how many connections my Postgres database can take, but I'm not familiar enough with it to know for sure.